# how to work with list of elements in page object model

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

In the below code snippet, how can I use osList and featureList using typescript can you please help me with this. I need to know how to work with a list of elements in the page object model like submitName function.

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe';

const label = Selector('label');

class Feature {
constructor (text) {
this.label = label.withText(text);
this.checkbox = this.label.find('input[type=checkbox]');
}
}

class OperatingSystem {
constructor (text) {
this.label = label.withText(text);
this.radioButton = this.label.find('input[type=radio]');
}
}

export default class Page {
constructor () {
this.nameInput = Selector('#developer-name');
this.triedTestCafeCheckbox = Selector('#tried-test-cafe');
this.populateButton = Selector('#populate');
this.submitButton = Selector('#submit-button');
this.results = Selector('.result-content');
this.commentsTextArea = Selector('#comments');

    this.featureList = [
        new Feature('Support for testing on remote devices'),
        new Feature('Re-using existing JavaScript code for testing'),
        new Feature('Running tests in background and/or in parallel in multiple browsers'),
        new Feature('Easy embedding into a Continuous integration system'),
        new Feature('Advanced traffic and markup analysis')
    ];

    this.osList = [
        new OperatingSystem('Windows'),
        new OperatingSystem('MacOS'),
        new OperatingSystem('Linux')
    ];

    this.slider = {
        handle: Selector('.ui-slider-handle'),
        tick:   Selector('.slider-value')
    };

    this.interfaceSelect       = Selector('#preferred-interface');
    this.interfaceSelectOption = this.interfaceSelect.find('option');
    this.submitButton          = Selector('#submit-button');
}

async submitName (name) {
    await t
        .typeText(this.nameInput, name)
        .click(this.submitButton);
}
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4):

I can describe this to you based on the [TestCafe's basic example](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/tree/master/examples/basic). First, you need to change the [`page-model` file](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/examples/basic/page-model.js) extension to `ts` and create this file according to the TypeScript rules (for example, see [my gist](https://gist.github.com/helen-dikareva/1974ced6f40d19e94d3fe5f2c678034e)). Then, you can change [the `test` file](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/blob/master/examples/basic/test.js) extension to `ts` and start test execution like you do it for any `js` tests, e. g. `testcafe chrome test.ts`.